# jQuery set multiple values of a <select> without using multiple=yes

Tags: jquery, select

i'm lookin for an method, to set the more than one value of an  without using the multiple funktion.

```
$("#multiselect .auswahl .options input").change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $("option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']",ele).attr("selected",true);
}else{
    $("option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']",ele).attr("selected",false);
}
});
```

This is HTML

```
<select name="kategorie[]" class="select">
   <option value="0" selected="">Bitte auswählen</option>
   <option value="2">A</option>
   <option value="3">B</option>
</select>
```

The Problem is, after sending the Form, the PHP gives only 1 value.
Is there a possibility to get more than 1 selected option without using multiple?

Or is there a Way to Style the multiple like an not multiple?

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards

Chris

Comment: What's wrong with using multiple select element?

Comment: any reason for not using multiple select

Comment: It should look like not multiple. The Layout should look like a select without multiple. I'm trying to create a Widget by my own, which do the job for the multiple select.

Comment: Use js to put choosed options into separate array and create hidden input with correct 'name' field. So all your parameters will be sent to the server. Also you can avoid of creating hidden element, just send your form info via js, e.g. AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You may add hidden field for every selected element on selection changing or change which data posts on .submit event for form or create select input  with display:none and multiple="true". There is a lot of original ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This jquery ui based widget provides a way to present multiselect with a similar look as the normal select.

http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget